# value set by javascript is not saved in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript, events, onblur

i am having two textboxes and a label in a gridview control, i am adding a javascript function to the second textbox onblur event attribute and display the result in the label, the function works fine and result is displayed in the label, but when i am saving the grid data into the database, the label is returned 0 or empty, but i am able to see the value , how to overcome this.

thanks and regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your label is not persisted in the ViewState because it does not consists as a 'Form' control. You could use a hidden Textbox to accomplish that, there are probably better ways tho.

Comment: i tried with hidden field , it is working on certain systems and not in certain systems , is there any browser settings which is preventing this action. the browser in which it is not working is firefox 3.5.5 any inputs?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link that answers your question.

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/65/ViewState-form-fields-labels-and-Javascript

If I understand correctly, (please correct me if I am wrong)
it is the [IPostBackDataHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler.aspx) ([more info](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/184406457)) that handles data in a server input field control when it was changed by the client (Javascript). A label control is not an input field therefore changes made in the client are not saved.

Here is a quote from the link above:

> ViewState's  job is to manage any
> changes to the initial state of server
> controls, if those changes are made
> programmatically on the server, or if
> changes made by user interaction are
> passed to the server. This does not
> include restoring the values of form
> inputs such as TextBoxes or the
> selected item in a CheckBox. There is
> a common misconception that form
> values are managed by ViewState. They
> are not. Never have been. These values
> are managed and restored purely by
> IPostBackDataHandler.
>
> IPostBackDataHandler is a massive boon
> to web developers who were brought up
> on other server-side technologies,
> such as classic ASP, PHP etc. In the
> "olden" days, we used to have to
> manually wire up every form field to
> display the originally posted value,
> so that user's weren't presented with
> an empty form to fill in all over
> again, if it had failed server-side
> validation. IPostBackDataHandler means
> we never have to do that again.

As mentioned in another answer using a hidden value to also hold the changes made by the Javascript should work.